# How to create a historical database in Excel from monthly user data

Tags: excel, database, formula

I am currently working on a dashboard which uses user data from a device. Every month a new data set will be provided and has to be processed by Excel in order to convert this raw data in something useful. Also  I want Excel to store this data for graphs which shows over time development of the amount of users.

In new data sets for each month, the devices which have been retired are removed from the data set which is what I need for my over time graphs.

The data set contains over 28 columns of different types of data and has approx. 20,000 users in it.

Currently I have this VBA code which works for the first line in Excel:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim Organization_Group_Name As String
Dim Device_Model As String
Dim AcqDate As Date
Dim ws as Worksheet
Dim ws_origin as Worksheet
Dim Last_Item as Long
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Database")
Set ws_origin = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Input")

'Input sheet
With ws_origin
    Organization_Group_Name = .Range("C2").Value
    Device_Model = .Range("M2").Value
    AcqDate = .Range("BA2").Value
End With

'Output in Database sheet
If ws.Range("A1").Value <> "" Then
    Last_Item = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
Else
    Last_Item = 1
End If

ws.Cells(Last_Item + 1, 0).Value = Organization_Group_Name
ws.Cells(Last_Item + 1, 1).Value = Device_Model
ws.Cells(Last_Item + 1, 2).Value = AcqDate

End Sub
```

It does the job on the "Database" page (Picks the next empty line etc.)

Right now, How can I code it so that it copies the entire column (Column A, B & C) Regardless of the amount of lines

Best Regards.

Comment: Welcome to SO! This is a very broad question. You should make your own research, try to generate your code/formulas and ask when you have any problem and we will be glad to help you. In order to achieve your goal, the easiest way is through Excel VBA. One first step could be to use the Macro Recorder and try to do some of your processes with it. When you get stacked, feel free to ask.

Comment: Hi There! It is broad indeed. I have figured out something right know.

Comment: I have posted my VBA code in this thread, by editting it becaus it was too long for a comment :)

Comment: I already edit your post in order to not to point a few things... Regarding your question. What is your plan? Did you test your code? How do you want to save that information? Where?

Comment: I've tested your code, and it gave Error 1004: "Application defined or object-defined error". I looked over it multiple times because there is probably an error in the reference to any of my sheets, but I can't figure it out.

The plan: Select three columns of data and paste it into the 'Database' worksheet in order to create a historic overview. The formula I posted did work, but only copied the first row of information, and not all the rows in the data set.

So data from 'Input' to 'Database' 
As where Input consists out of raw data from a system with 28 columns

Comment: When you run it, if you press debug, it will show you which line is failing as it will be highlighted.

Comment: @DavidGarcíaBodego When I debug it highlights this one first:
ws.Cells(Last_Item + 1, 0).Value = Organization_Group_Name

Comment: ***I already edit*** the code an place one comment. There was a mistake on the Cells position. Cells it is working on relative position, considering "A1" as 1,1, and increasing in rows,columns. (This is better that Range when you need to loop). The position can be never 0 as the first column is 1. As I took your offset position it was my mistake to not to shift.